# JSON argument deserialization inconsistency

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-mvc-5

On one hand I have this model:

```
public class DocumentAccessPermissions
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsGroup { get; set; }

    public bool ViewDetails { get; set; }

    public bool Download { get; set; }

    public bool EditDetails { get; set; }

    public bool Modify { get; set; }

    public bool Delete { get; set; }
}
```

I am sending it to the controller like this:

```
var documentId = $('#hdnDocumentId', popup).val();
var items = [];
$.each(someData, function (index, item) {
    items.push({
        Name: item.Name,
        IsGroup: item.IsGroup,
        ViewDetails: item.ViewDetails,
        EditDetails: item.EditDetails,
        Modify: item.Modify,
        Download: item.Download,
        Delete: item.Delete
    });
});

$.ajax({
    url: $('#hdnSaveLink', popup).val(),
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        id: documentId,
        permissions: items
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
    }
});
```

And the controller receives it like this:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> AccessManager_Save(string id, Models.DocumentAccessPermissions[] permissions)
{
    var documents = new Models.Documents();
    bool success = await documents.SetAccessPermissions(id, permissions);
    return Json(success);
}
```

And it works. I receive the array of objects correctly deserialized without any additional work.

On the other hand I have this model:

```
public class BillingsCategoryTermItemForEdit
{
    public int ID { get; internal set; }
    public bool? InvoiceAttachement1 { get; internal set; }
    public short? InvoicingStartToEndDate { get; internal set; }
    public short? PreInvoicingDays { get; internal set; }
    public string PreInvoicingDaysType { get; internal set; }
    public short? Reccurence { get; internal set; }
    public short? ReccurenceDay { get; internal set; }
    public short? ReccurenceDayOfWeek { get; internal set; }
    public short? ReccurenceType { get; internal set; }
    public short? ReccurenceWeek { get; internal set; }
}
```

I am trying to send the data like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/GroupM/InvoiceTerms/EditInvoicingFrequency_Save',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        item: {
            ID: ID,
            ReccurenceType: ReccurenceType,
            Reccurence: Reccurence,
            ReccurenceDay: ReccurenceDay,
            ReccurenceDayOfWeek: ReccurenceDayOfWeek,
            ReccurenceWeek: ReccurenceWeek,
            InvoiceAttachement1: InvoiceAttachement1,
            InvoicingStartToEndDate: InvoicingStartToEndDate,
            PreInvoicingDaysType: PreInvoicingDaysType,
            PreInvoicingDays: PreInvoicingDays
        },  
        mediumGroupIDs: resultingMediumTypes
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (message) {
    }
});
```

I am trying to receive it like this supposing it will work like in the previous example:

```
public virtual async Task<JsonResult> EditInvoicingFrequency_Save(Models.BillingsCategoryTermItemForEdit item, string mediumGroupIDs)
{
    string username = UserManager.GetFullUsername();
    var billings = new Models.Billings();
    bool success = await billings.Save(item, mediumGroupIDs, username, MVC.GroupM.Name);
    return Json(success);
}
```

It doesn't work. I am getting the object with zeros and nulls (default values). I checked the requests sent to the server and they look ok. Data is sent, only that in the second example it is not correctly deserialized.

I would be grateful for any insight.

Btw. I know that I can use JSON.stringify and then deserialize the string on the server side. I am not looking for that solution. I am looking for the reason this way works in the first but not in the second example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be because the second class has the setters internal? I mean serializable properties should have both public set and get accessors, otherwise the serializer shouldn't have access to setting values.

Comment: Now I feel kind of silly. :) Thanks for the answer I'll rate as soon as I confirm it tomorrow.

Comment: You were right. It was the internal setter. Can't believe that I didn't even notice that they are set. Thanks.